# Built-in webcam not detected on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam, lsusb

I'm having trouble getting my built-in webcam to work. I want to understand more about how drivers work and how a built-in webcam can be detected in the terminal or found. Here is my lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 046: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b336 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0023 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your built-in webcam `04f2:b336 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd` isn't listed under [Linux UVC supported devices](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices). You can test your webcam by installing `guvcview` (webcam viewer) to try out first and confirm it is working or not. Then, refer to [this Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam#Driver_installation) for next clue.